# How do you move React Native Gifted Chat up the screen?

Tags: css, react-native

I have an app with a bottom tab navigator, and also React-Native-Gifted-Chat. The chat starts from the bottom of the screen, and as such the bottom tab navigator blocks it.
[Bottom nav bar blocking chat on Webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj4uL.png)
[Bottom nav bar blocking chat on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L1Iq.jpg)

I tried doing

```
<GiftedChat
      messages={messages}
      onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
      }}
style={{bottom: 20, position: absolute}}
    />
```

and it did not work. Is there anyway I can move the chat upwards so then I can have both the bottom nav bar and the chat show and work perfectly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in `View` and set style for that view

```
<View style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: 20}}>
  <GiftedChat
      messages={messages}
      onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
      }}
    />
</View>
```